# Python + cx_oracle connection failed

Tags: python, oracle, database-connection, cx-oracle

I have 2 servers:

1st - Oracle Server, 2nd - Server with SQL Developer.

SQL Developer has connection with Oracle, it works good.

I am trying to get connection to Oracle wia python + cx_oracle, i have the following code:

```
import cx_Oracle

try:
    dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("Oracle_server_ip", "1521", "Oracle_server_sid")
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="Oracle_user", password="Oracle_password", dsn=dsnStr)
    print ('CONNECTED TO ORACLE, VER: ' + con.version)
    cur = con.cursor()
except:
    print ('Connection Failed')
```

It works good on the server, where Oracle is located.

But it doesn't work on another server, where SQL Developer is located.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Remove your `try..except` so you get an error message, then edit your post with the error message you get.

Comment: File "<string>", line 55 in <module> cx_Oracle InterfaceError. Unable to acquire Oracle enviroment handle. 55th stroke is: con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password", dsn=dsnStr)

Comment: Try removing your keywords from the `.connect` function: `con = cx_Oracle.connect("Oracle_user", "Oracle_password", dsnStr)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40154336/7220776).

Comment: I can connect to oracle, when run code from Oracle server, i can't connect to oracle, when run code from Remote Server

Comment: You might want to look at this http://www.ptrackapp.com/apclassys-notes/how-to-install-cx_oracle/ and make sure you have all of the SDKs and junk installed on the other server.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest upgrading to cx_Oracle 6 as the error message that is returned is likely going to be better. You can do that via this command:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

At a guess, however, you are missing an Oracle Client on the second machine. The easiest to install is the instant client which you can find [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html).